# Cannot view any reports on analytics, keep receiving error

Tags: google-analytics, google-sites

During the Google Analytics setup process for my website ([www.supersmashbrosinstitute.com](https://www.supersmashbrosinstitute.com)) I received the following error:

[image: Internal Error. Please try again later. Analytics has encountered an unexpected condition and cannot fulfill your request.]

My website was built with Google sites and the domain registration is provided by GoDaddy. I have the forwarding part of the site working fine.

When I went to set up the Google Analytics tracking ID however, I ran into an issue. It gave me the above error. I was still able to go into the "Properties and Apps" portion of the web page and grab the Tracking ID from there, thus allowing me to input the tracking ID on the Google Sites side.

I republished with the tracking ID input onto the Google Sites side of things, but now whenever I go to the reports dashboard, into the realtime reports section or any of the audience views, it constantly gives me this error.

Is there any way to tell what is going on here? I don't have any filters (just trying to use Analytics at all is giving me pain) so I'm confused as to what the problem is. I've checked ["common tracking setup issues"](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009683?hl=en) but nothing they are talking about there looks recognizable.

Can someone give me pointers on what this error could mean? I've "tried again later" but it's been a whole day... how much later should I try again or is this an issue on my configuration side of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw that problem before, not 100% sure but some people had problem because of AdBlocker so first if you have one, try to delete it and than you should have access back to your reports.
The other possible solution is that your url might look like this :

https://ads.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#home/blablabla

if that is the casse change "ads" to "www"

https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#home/blablabla

Comment: This seems like the correct answer, though I have a hard time verifying as the problem just sort of "went away" on my computer. I will look into it further later tonight.

Comment: Glad that i could provide help :)

Answer (score 2):

I stumble upon this problem after using GA for 2 years without any problems. I searched and the same answer related to ad block popped up but I don't have any ad-block on my browser. I turned off all extensions but still didn't work. I use google chrome so I thought there might be something in the browser that I can't find so I used another browser, firefox, and no problem there. I can see all the reports without that message. definitely, there's something in my google chrome messing with it. Of course, I haven't removed and reinstalled it yet to see if the problem is fixed in it but since I was frustrated and couldn't find the answer, I'm writing this so it can help someone having the same problem. So change the browser.